# MS Access - execute a saved query by name in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

How do I execute a saved query in MS Access 2007 in VBA?

I do not want to copy and paste the SQL into VBA. I rather just execute the name of the query.

This doesn't work ... VBA can't find the query.

```
CurrentDb.Execute queryname
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "yourQueryName", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

OR

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("yourQueryName")
```

Comment: I do not want to edit. Will this execute my update and insert queries?

Comment: Yes it will run Update and Insert queries.

Comment: Its an append query that works manually, but not in my vba code. Can I not use a append saved query?

Comment: it should work without any issues, can you edit your question and post more code?

Answer (score 12):

You should investigate why VBA can't find *queryname*.

I have a saved query named *qryAddLoginfoRow*. It inserts a row with the current time into my *loginfo* table.  That query runs successfully when called by name by `CurrentDb.Execute`.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "qryAddLoginfoRow"
```

My guess is that either *queryname* is a variable holding the name of a query which doesn't exist in the current database's QueryDefs collection, or *queryname* is the literal name of an existing query but you didn't enclose it in quotes.

**Edit**:
You need to find a way to accept that *queryname* does not exist in the current db's QueryDefs collection.  Add these 2 lines to your VBA code just before the `CurrentDb.Execute` line.

```
Debug.Print "queryname = '" & queryname & "'"
Debug.Print CurrentDb.QueryDefs(queryname).Name
```

The second of those 2 lines will trigger run-time error 3265, "*Item not found in this collection.*"  Then go to the Immediate window to verify the name of the query you're asking `CurrentDb` to `Execute`.

Comment: Its an append query that works manually, but not in my vba code. Can I not use a append saved query?

Comment: The query I described **is** an append query ... it adds (appends) a row to my loginfo table.

Answer (score 5):

To use CurrentDb.Execute, your query must be an action query, AND in quotes.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "queryname"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thre are 2 ways to run Action Query in MS Access VBA:**

---

1. You can use `DoCmd.OpenQuery` statement. This allows you to control these warnings:

[image: Action Query Warning Example]

BUT! Keep in mind that DoCmd.SetWarnings will remain set even after the function completes. This means that you need to make sure that you leave it in a condition that suits your needs

```vb
Function RunActionQuery(QueryName As String)
    On Error GoTo Hell              'Set Error Hanlder
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True          'Turn On Warnings
    DoCmd.OpenQuery QueryName       'Execute Action Query
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False         'Turn On Warnings
    Exit Function
Hell:
    If Err.Number = 2501 Then       'If Query Was Canceled
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation
    Else                            'Everything else
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    End If
End Function
```

---

2. You can use `CurrentDb.Execute` method. This alows you to keep Action Query failures
   under control. The SetWarnings flag does not affect it. Query is executed always without warnings.

```vb
Function RunActionQuery()
    'To Catch the Query Error use dbFailOnError option
    On Error GoTo Hell
    CurrentDb.Execute "Query1", dbFailOnError
    Exit Function
Hell:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Function
```

It is worth noting that the `dbFailOnError` option responds only to data processing failures. If the Query contains an error (such as a typo), then a runtime error is generated, even if this option is not specified

---

In addition, you can use `DoCmd.Hourglass True` and `DoCmd.Hourglass False` to control the mouse pointer if your Query takes longer