# Updating information in an Access table linked to SharePoint

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, sharepoint

I have a table in Access linked to a SharePoint list.  The table is comprised of about 15 fields whose contents are originally pulled from another data source (in Excel format). There are an additional 10 or so fields after the original 15 that make up a questionnaire (added via SharePoint) that contain answers to questions about the first 15 fields.

The data in the first 15 fields needs to be updated periodically when new data from my external source is available to download.  A lot of the information will remain the same, however some of the fields within each of the rows will change and need to be updated.  It is also important that the 10 fields that contain the questionnaire are not modified at all during this process.

Is there a way for me to easily update the cells that have changed using an Update query or something similar?  The data does have a unique identifier column (ID NUMBER) that is present on the current SharePoint list and the external data source.

I was thinking from a logical standpoint to put the new external data into a table, find the ID Number in the SP list and new external data, compare the values in the rest of the row on the SP list to the row of the external data, and if a value is different update the cell with the value from the external data. Not sure how to accomplish this using Access queries though.

I really appreciate any help at all! If you need more information, please let me know.  If you think there's a more logical way to do this, please let me know your feedback!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get started:
http://workerthread.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/using-access-2007-to-update-sharepoint-lists/

After you get the connection set up, it's just a matter of writing the queries correctly. If you need to run multiple queries periodically, you can setup a form with buttons, and attach some VBA code to the buttons that runs the queries.
[MS Access - execute a saved query by name in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929009/ms-access-execute-a-saved-query-by-name-in-vba)