# Using parameter from form in IN statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with several inputs, that are then passed on to a query. This is pretty straightforward, except I want one of my parameters to be used in an IN statement in my sql like such:

```
Select sum(id) as numobs from table where year=[form]![form1]![year] and (group in([form]![form1]![group]));
```

When [form]![form1]![group]="3,4" it querys "group in(34)" and if [form]![form1]![group]="3, 4" then I get an error saying "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated..."

I would like to be able to enter multiple numbers separated by a comma in a field in a form, and then have a query use the result in an IN statement. Does this seem doable?

I know with VBA I could do if-then statements to look at every possible combination of group numbers (there are over 40 groups so combinatorically there are over 4 trillion ways to combine the 40+ groups since the sum of 42 choose k from 0 to 42 is over 4 trillion) so using the IN statement seems like a better option.

Any ideas on how to get the IN statement to work with a parameter from a form?

Thanks

Comment: You mean `group in (3, 4)`? I don't know if Access supports multi-value parameters but that's probably what you should be looking at. You wouldn't need 4 trillion tests even if you ended up using VBA.

Comment: https://accessexperts.com/blog/2013/09/23/are-you-in-or-are-you-out-not-in/

Comment: The link says in(3, 4) is correct not in (3, 4)

Comment: The space is not significant and most SQL is written with it there. I was concerned about the comma though: you wrote `34` which might have changed this into an entirely different question.

Comment: Here's is are some suggested approaches. You could also try another approach by populating another table with the values of your "groups" and using `IN (select group from <mygroups>)`. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210530

Comment: The problem is when I set the parameter in the form equal to "3,4" it reads it as "34" and if I set it to "3, 4" with a space I get an error

Comment: It's probably doing some implicit casting from a string value to a numeric. The comma is probably being ignored as a thousands separator. The approach with a single parameter isn't going to word. Read the article if you want an approach based on substring matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be very simply done with a sub in a VBA module:

```vb
Sub MakeTheQuery()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strElements As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    strSQL = "SELECT Sum(id) AS numobs " & _
        "FROM ErrorKey WHERE ErrorKey.ID In ({0});"

    ' Example: "3,5"
    strElements = Forms!YourForm!YourControl.Caption

    ' Assign SQL to query
    db.QueryDefs!YourQuery.SQL = Replace(strSQL, "{0}", strElements)

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I implement this? I entered this code into the module for my form, but how do I call it/use it? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Carl I've edited the question with some implementation details. You just need to run this sub to change the query (`Call MakeTheQuery`) and then [run the query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929009/ms-access-execute-a-saved-query-by-name-in-vba). Make sure you replace all of the names of things, too.

Comment: @Carl I attempted to edit the above answer, seeing as it is more streamlined, but my edit was rejected. I've added implementation information on my answer.

Comment: @st78: Read the question and answer again, please. The value is pulled from the _Caption_ property which is beyond user control.

Answer (score 3):

I can't figure out a way to do it with `IN`.

My solution: in a VBA module in your database, write a sub to build a query based on the values in the form control. Let's use the `Split` method to make an array, which we can iterate through to build a query.

```vb
Sub MakeTheQuery()
Dim strSQL As String, db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

strSQL = "SELECT sum(id) AS numobs _
FROM table WHERE ("

Value = Forms!YourForm!YourControl.Caption
'The property may vary with controls ^

'Create an array from the control values
anArray = Split(Value, ",")

'Add to the query for each value
For i = LBound(anArray) To (UBound(anArray) - 1)
strSQL = strSQL & " ErrorKey.ID = " & anArray(i) & " OR"
Next i

'Wrap it all up
strSQL = strSQL & " ErrorKey.ID = " & anArray(UBound(anArray)) & ")"

'Assign SQL to query
db.QueryDefs!YourQuery.SQL = strSQL

End Sub
```

Please keep in mind this assumes that the string from the form control will be formatted with **no spaces**, but you can easily change that by using `anArray = Split(Value, ", ")` instead (note the space add after the comma).

To assign the VBA sub to a button or other control on your form by going to `Layout View`, clicking on a control, going to the `Event` tab on the Property Sheet, hitting the <kbd>...</kbd> button beside the On Click. Hit `Code Builder`. Put `Call MakeTheQuery` in the sub that it builds for you. If you want to run the query, too, put `DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourQuery"`.

You can also use this method to [build a more complex, dynamic parameter query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199777/access-dynamic-query-better-to-build-one-conditional-sql-query-or-multiple-que/28199953#28199953).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider Instr() function instead of In. Assuming you are generating the numbered list procedurally rather than forcing the end user to type a comma-separated list, you can change the format. We typically use pipe separators, so for example, the input may look like this:
    `[form]![form1]![group]="|3|4|"`
This is passed to the query as a single string parameter and tested in the Instr() function as follows:
    `Instr([form]![form1]![group],"|" & group & "|")>0
    ' Instr() returns a numeric value of the position in the first argument where the second argument is found.`
The pipes ensure we don't get false positives (for example, finding 3 when we pass 34). We use this with multi-select listboxes and a custom VBA function, but it's perfectly viable any time you have control over the format.
[Instr Function - support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b)