# Ms Access does not recognize as a Valid field name

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

```
TRANSFORM IIF(IsNull(First(wrhCode)),'' ,First(wrhCode) & ', '  ) AS FirstOfwrhCode 
   SELECT whiitemID AS ItemID, 
          whiItemName AS Name, 
          Sum(Qty) AS Quantity
     FROM (SELECT wrhID,  
                  wrhCode, 
                  whiitemID,
                  whiItemName,
                  Sum(whiQty) AS QTY 
            FROM tblWarehouseItem AS WI 
                 INNER JOIN tblWarehouse AS W ON WI.whiwrhID = W.wrhID
           WHERE whiActive = True                           
             AND whiwrhID IN (Forms.frmStockControl.Form.txtwrhIDs) 
        GROUP BY wrhID, wrhCode, whiItemName, whiitemID)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
 GROUP BY whiitemID, whiItemName
    PIVOT 'wrhID' & wrhID;
```

I have this query to my form but it does not work:
But if i edit :

```
 AND whiwrhID IN (Forms.frmStockControl.Form.txtwrhIDs)
```

to:

```
 AND whiwrhID IN (26,27,29)
```

Is working any ideas how to fix the error

Comment: Do you receive an "error" or is just not working?

Comment: Did you try `Forms!frmStockControl!txtwhrIDs`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

```
    whiwrhID IN (26,27,29)
```

must be hard coded in SQL.

Your only option is to adjust the SQL before calling the query.

Answer (score 1):

Why not [use VBA to build a dynamic query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779515/using-parameter-from-form-in-in-statement/29782786#29782786)?

You can initiate a sub MakeAQuery through an event or macro to modify your `IN` statement to whatever you need:

```vb
Sub MakeAQuery()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strElements As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()

'Your current SQL with a parameter in the IN clause
    strSQL = "TRANSFORM IIF(IsNull(First(wrhCode)),'' ,First(wrhCode) & ', '  ) _
    AS FirstOfwrhCode _
    SELECT whiitemID AS ItemID, _
      whiItemName AS Name, _
      Sum(Qty) AS Quantity _
    FROM (SELECT wrhID, _
              wrhCode, _
              whiitemID, _
              whiItemName, _
              Sum(whiQty) AS QTY _
        FROM tblWarehouseItem AS WI _
             INNER JOIN tblWarehouse AS W ON WI.whiwrhID = W.wrhID _
       WHERE whiActive = True _                  
         AND whiwrhID In ({0})_
       GROUP BY wrhID, wrhCode, whiItemName, whiitemID) _ 
    AS [%$##@_Alias]
    GROUP BY whiitemID, whiItemName
    PIVOT 'wrhID' & wrhID;"

    ' Retrieve your IDs for the IN clause
    strElements = Forms.frmStockControl.Form.txtwrhIDs

    ' Assign SQL to query
    db.QueryDefs!YourQuery.SQL = Replace(strSQL, "{0}", strElements)

End Sub
```

To assign this VBA sub to a button or other control on your form...

1. Go to to `Layout View` for your form.
2. Clicking on a control, go to the `Event` tab on the Property Sheet.
3. Hit the <kbd>...</kbd> button beside the On Click property. (You could do this for any event property; `OnClick` works when you click on the control.)
4. Choose `Code Builder` and `Ok`.
5. Put `Call MakeTheQuery` in the sub that it builds for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
Forms.frmStockControl.Form.txtwrhIDs.Text
```